# Why is 'r' used in regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly do “u” and “r”string flags in Python, and what are raw string litterals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte)

```
p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1')

p.search('Paris in the the spring').group()
```

What is the meaning of `r` in the 1st line?

Answer (score 2):

`r` designates a raw string in Python, which has different rules than a standard string, such as you don't have to escape backslashes and other special chars.

Comment: when using r why \w is still treated as escape sequence and not as literal.

Comment: As far as I know and in the documentation it doesn't say anything about \w being treated as an escape sequence.  In fact it is not an escaped sequence.  `\w` has no meaning.  http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: You can check this link http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html             here it is mentioned about \w

Comment: Yes, `r"\w"` will match any alphanumeric character.  Using r allows you to type `r"\w"` instead of `"//w"`.  The r allows you to include Python Escape sequences inside of a string without needing to escape the \.  I feel like I am not being clear to you.

Comment: thanks ajon. Now I understood in better way.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation.

Comment: when using r why \w is still treated as escape sequence and not as literal ?

Comment: `\w` is not an escape sequence, it's a special sequence (towards the bottom of the [syntax section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) of the `re` documentation).